# using zuck js library in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to implement stories effect in ionic app by using in zuck.js library
[zuck.js](https://github.com/ramon82/zuck.js/blob/master/README.md)

I install it

```
npm install zuck
```

then import it in my home component

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as zuck from "zuck";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

   stories = new Zuck('stories', {

    backNative:true,

    autoFullScreen:'false',

    skin:'Snapgram',

    avatars:'true',

    list:false,

    cubeEffect:'true',

    localStorage:true,

    stories: [],

    });
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
```

but it shows me error buck Zuck with capital letter not defined

> referenceError: Zuck is not defined ReferenceError: Zuck is not defined at new HomePage

I thought to change it to

```
import * as Zuck from "zuck";
```

but I get same error.

UPDATE!!!
I changed the import to

```
import Zuck from 'zuck';
```

I get the error

> Runtime Error
>   Cannot find module "react"

is not possible to use zuck.js in ionic?

after declaring Zuck i want to create object and I get

> Cannot read property 'id' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'id'
>   of null at new window.ZuckitaDaGalera.window.Zuck
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:115204:23) at new HomePage

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'zuck.js/zuck.js';
declare var Zuck;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  stories = new Zuck('stories', {
    backNative: true,
    autoFullScreen: 'false',
    skin: 'Snapgram',
    avatars: 'true',
    list: false,
    cubeEffect: 'true',
    localStorage: true,
    stories: [
      {
        id: 'vision',
        photo: 'https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/QJcTT2ab-sYWwOGrxJc0MXSt3UI=/2011/10/27/a66dfbb7-fdc7-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/android-wallpaper5_2560x1600_1.jpg',
        name: 'Tech',
        link: '',
        lastUpdated: 1492665454,
        items: [
          this.buildItem('1', 'photo', 3, 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782474226020200448/zDo-gAo0_400x400.jpg','', '', false, 1492665454),
          this.buildItem('2', 'photo', 3, 'https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/ironman/images/5/59/Robert-Downey-Jr-Tony-Stark-Iron-Man-3-Marvel-Disney.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130611164804', '', '',false, 1492665454),
          this.buildItem('3', 'video', 0, 'https://scontent-gru2-2.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/14965218_193969377722724_482497862983221248_n.mp4', 'https://scontent-gru2-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/10597412_455246124639813_1360162248_n.jpg', '', false, 1492665454),
        ],
      }],
  });

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  buildItem(id, type, length, src, preview, link, seen, time) {

    // Using object short-hand (id: id)
    return {id,type,length,src,preview,link,seen,time,
    };

    }

}
```

Comment: `import Zuck from 'zuck';` should be the right one. The error with react is most probably related to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I posted my comment I realized that you are using the wrong npm package for `zuck`. [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zuck) npm package is something completely different and thats why you are getting the react module error. Use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zuck.js) one instead:

```
npm install zuck.js
```

And import it like that:

```
import 'zuck.js/zuck.js';
declare var Zuck;
```

Comment: nice try. but I install it and it shows me red line under the 'zuck.js' with the error: cannot find module 'zuck.js'

Comment: really weird because I see the zack.js in the modules and package.json

Comment: thank you, can you see on my updated post the new issue I get when I try to make object of ZUCK

Comment: That would be another question. But its probably because you have no container defined in your html file which has an id named `stories`. Add `<div id="stories"></div>` to your template.

Comment: I checked and i opened new issue, if you can see please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474761/zuck-js-library-cannot-read-property-id-of-null-at-new-window-zuckitadagalera