# zuck js library cannot read property 'id' of null at new window.ZuckitaDaGalera.window

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement stories using zuck.js in my ionic 3 app and I get this error

```
Cannot read property 'id' of null at new window.ZuckitaDaGalera.window.Zuck (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:115204:23) at new HomePage
```

I checked in [docs](https://github.com/ramon82/zuck.js/) and it looks like I send the right data but I get this error and actually stuck with it.

HomePage component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'zuck.js/zuck.js';
declare var Zuck;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  stories = new Zuck('stories', {
    backNative: true,
    autoFullScreen: 'false',
    skin: 'Snapgram',
    avatars: 'true',
    list: false,
    cubeEffect: 'true',
    localStorage: true,
    stories: [
      {
        id: 'vision',
        photo: 'https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/QJcTT2ab-sYWwOGrxJc0MXSt3UI=/2011/10/27/a66dfbb7-fdc7-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/android-wallpaper5_2560x1600_1.jpg',
        name: 'Tech',
        link: '',
        lastUpdated: 1492665454,
        items: [
          this.buildItem('1', 'photo', 3, 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782474226020200448/zDo-gAo0_400x400.jpg', '', false, 1492665454,''),
          this.buildItem('2', 'photo', 3, 'https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/ironman/images/5/59/Robert-Downey-Jr-Tony-Stark-Iron-Man-3-Marvel-Disney.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130611164804', '', '', false, 1492665454),
          this.buildItem('3', 'video', 0, 'https://scontent-gru2-2.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/14965218_193969377722724_482497862983221248_n.mp4', 'https://scontent-gru2-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/10597412_455246124639813_1360162248_n.jpg', '', false, 1492665454),
        ],
      }],
  });

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  buildItem(id, type, length, src, preview, link, seen, time) {

    // Using object short-hand (id: id)
    return {id,type,length,src,preview,link,seen,time,
    };

    }

}
```

the html view

```
<div id="stories"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `Zuck` related code somewhere where the current template with your `div` is already available. Currently it is `null` because you are trying to access the template before the component is even ready. Putting the code into `ionViewDidEnter()` should work.

Also declare the `stories` variable like this then:

```
let stories = ...
```

And move the `buildItem()` method out of the constructor-body, thats not where a function belongs.

Comment: I see the slides of the images but when I just want to press on the I get "runtime error invalid views to insert". what is it?

Comment: I don't know, you will have to do a little debugging yourself.